# How estimate the error of chemkin 2.55 results?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, modeling, combustion, numerical-methods

I've been using chemkin 2.55 for preliminary calculations of premixed laminar H_2 and CH_4 combustion and in some of the calculations, the solver fails.

There is a way to hypothesize the calculation by using figures (results.bin) close to the failed calculation so that it can (what I imagine) perform a type of interpolation.

Is there any documentation, or anyone with experience using this program that would know how to adequately evaluate the "error" of these interpolated solutions?